# Data from the object doesn't convert when using JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm stuck in this weird issue that I'm having hard time in understanding what's doing on. When a button is clicked it calls the function `onSubmit`. What `onSubmit` function should do is stringify is the object to JSON however for me this doesn't happen. The result I get when I `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));` is `[[]]`. When I `console.log(obj);` I can see the object.

I was not able to replicate the same issue in `playcode.io` and `codesandbox.io`

```
  async function onSubmit() {
    let l = [];
    l["Channel"] = undefined;
    l["MetricsData"] = [
      { id: 1, name: "CPA", year: "" },
      { id: 2, name: "Average Gift", year: "" },
      { id: 3, name: "Average Gift Upgrade %", year: "" }
    ];

    let obj = [];
    l.Channel = 1;
    obj.push(l);

    console.log(obj);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)); //[[]]
  
  }
```

Comment: You're using `l` like it's an object, so it should be an object - `let l = {};`

Comment: `[]` is an array not an object literal. The properties are technically being added to the array object but not in a way that `JSON.stringify` can understand - you want to use curly braces `{}` to define an object.

Comment: https://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed in comments, you're instantiating `l` as an array and then attempt populating named keys (`Channel`, `Metricsdata`).
**Note**: Technically, [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) are [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), but they're special objects (their keys are intended to be numeric and they also have a few extra props and methods, specific to arrays - e.g: `length`, `pop`, `push`, `slice`, etc...). Use the link above to read more about arrays.

What you need to do is use `l` as an object (e.g: `{}`):

```js
const l = {
  Channel: 1,
  MetricsData: [
    { id: 1, name: "CPA", year: "" },
    { id: 2, name: "Average Gift", year: "" },
    { id: 3, name: "Average Gift Upgrade %", year: "" }
  ]
};

// Uncomment any of the following:

// console.log('object:', l);
// console.log('stringified object:', JSON.stringify(l));

const items = [];
items.push(l);
// console.log('items:', items);
// console.log('first item:', items[0]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(items));
```